# Cant upload new version of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi I Cant upload new version of wordpress through wordpress. It is rejecting my password to phpmysql. I know it will be something simple and the password is correct and gets me into phpmysql just not through the wordpress portal. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean by your statement, but you can't change your password, via WordPress, correct? If not, do you have access to the database that WordPress is on? PHPMyadmin?

Comment: No I can access the PHP but when I try to upgrade my wordpress in wordpress it prompts me to go give my PHP login details. But they are not accepted.Where do I go in the PHP to upgrade wordpress? Thanks